# How is a variable assigned a memory address?

Tags: operating-system

If I write an instruction x = 7, I understand x to be some address. What then assigns a memory address to x? Is this address a virtual address that is then translated into a physical memory address?

Comment: Partly your compiler, partly your operating system.

Comment: It's *highly* dependent on the environment you're working in, e.g., OS (if any), compiler, optimizations,... It might be in a register, it might be on the stack, it might be in a data segment, ... There's no general answer, especially without context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I write an instruction x = 7, I understand x to be some address. What then assigns a memory address to x?

It depends on the type of var `x`.

1. if `x` is a *global or static* variable, several tools will cooperate to give it an address

   - the compiler will write in the object file that it needs to store a global var named `x` with 4 bytes.
   - the linker will collect all the global vars in object files, put them in the *data segment*, and choose a position for them. For instance, `x` will be at `@data_segment+0x1000`. The linker will then modify all references to `x` in the code by `@data_segment+0x1000`
   - when it runs the program, the loader will first ask the operating system memory to store the different segments, including data segment. One then knows the value of `@data_segment` and the actual address of `x`<sup>1</sup>.
2. if `x` is a local variable, things are slightly simpler. All local vars are in the stack and their address is computed relatively to stack (or frame) pointer by the compiler. So address of `x` will be something like `@stack_pointer+8` and it is generated by the compiler. But its actual value is only known at execution and depends on the stack pointer.
3. if `x` is dynamically allocated (malloc-ed), its address is only known at run-time. `malloc()` asks the OS for chunks of memory and dynamically positions vars in it.  `x` will be put at a position that depends on free space in the memory managed by `malloc()`

> Is this address a virtual address that is then translated into a physical memory address?

All addresses seen by the computer are virtual addresses that are converted to physical memory addresses.

---

<sup>1</sup> Virtual addresses of program segments (including data segment) used to be constant for different executions of the program, but it is no longer true. For security reasons, they are [randomized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

Answer (score 0):

There are generally four ways this is done.

1) The variable is mapped to a hardware register. In that case x has no address.

2) The variable has an absolute address. This is usually considered bad form because the code using absolute addresses cannot be relocated; meaning it has to be placed in a fixed location in the address space. However, there are cases where a variable must be at a specific locations, such as some interfaces to devices.

In this case the address of x may be specified by the compiler or by the linker.

3) The variable is defined as an offset from a stack-related register. The is the method used to implement local variables in most programming languages. If you have 4-byte integers and say a C declaration like

int x, y ;

in a function with no other variables, there were be instructions at the top fo the function that look something like:

```
SUBL2 #8, SP ; Allocate 8 bytes from the stack
MOVL  SP, BP ; Set the Base Pointer Register to the start of the allocation
```

where SP is the stack pointer and BP is some based pointer register.

In that case,  x could then be the offset located at BP + 0 and, y could be at BP + 4.

Thus something like

```
x = y
```

would look like

MOVL X(BP), Y(BP)

or written as:

MOVL (BP), 4(BP)

The memory location of x and y are entirely determined at run time. Only the offset from the base pointer register is known. In fact, there could be multiple x and y active at the same time having different addresses if their containing function is called recursively or through an interrupt.

4) The memory location is another register offset (usually the program counter).

Let's say you are using traditional uppercase FORTRAN where all variable are static. It is common for the compiler to determine an location for a variable but refer to it using an offset from the program counter register (or some other register). The variable remains in a fixed place at run time but the location could be variable. Using such an offset allows the code to be position independent; meaning it can be loaded anywhere in memory. This allows the code to be used in shared libraries that can be used by multiple programs.

Usually the compiler sets some location for the variable and then that gets fixed by the linker.